# bad operand types for binary operator '-' in Prioritiy Queue

Tags: java, collections, queue, priority-queue

How do I get rid off this message?

```
bad operand types for binary operator '-'
    Queue<Long> heap = new PriorityQueue( (a,b)->b - a );
first type:  Object
second type: Object
```

```
import java.util.*; 
class solve {

    static long minCost(long arr[], int n) {
        
        Queue<Long> heap = new PriorityQueue( (a,b)-> b - a );
        
        long ans = 0;
        
        for( long i : arr )
            heap.add(i);
            
        while(!heap.isEmpty()){
            long f = heap.poll();
            
            if( heap.isEmpty()) return f+ans;
            
            long s = heap.poll();
            ans += f+s;
            heap.add(f+s);    
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a[] = {4, 3, 2, 6};
        System.out.println(minCost(a, 4));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `Comparator.reverseOrder()`?

Comment: First: `PriorityQueue` -> `PriorityQueue<>` and then fix the next errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use non-raw `PriorityQueue`, and cast the result of the subtraction to `int`:

```
Queue<Long> heap = new PriorityQueue<>( (a,b)-> (int) (b - a) );
```

Of course, this will give unexpected results if the difference in the longs exceeds the range of `int`.

It is easier just to use:

```
Queue<Long> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Even for `int` inputs, the distance between two values can be larger than the `int` value space. That’s why minus should not be used as comparator function, in general. You can use `(a,b)->Long.compare(b, a)` if you don’t use the already existing `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.